# Move semantic vs returning a shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I understand in C++ programmers are encouraged to use value semantics. But at my work, I noticed a pattern where some programmers use reference semantic, and to be precise, they use shared_ptr where I would use value semantic.

To give this a bit context, for example, I have an API that reads a Database Page and returns its content. I see there are two ways of doing it.

Choice 1 value semantic:

```
DBPage readDatabasePage(int number) { // number is the for which page to read
    DBPage page;
    ... // reading the database page

    return page; // here we have RVO/move semantic to help us so it is not inefficient
}
```

Choice 2 reference semantic:

```
std::shared_ptr<DBPage> readDatabasePage(int number) { // ditto
    std::shared_ptr<DBPage> page = std::make_shared<DBPage>();
    ...
    return page;
}
```

The second choice seems okay for me, as I cannot see a disadvantage of doing it this way. So what I want to understand is why we are encouraging people to use value semantic. What is wrong with choice 2 here?

Comment: I would compare return by value with using `std::unique_ptr`. When using `std::shared_ptr`, you get the advantage of having your object's ownership shared among multiple places. So, there is no single place where you decide the life-time of this object. This of course comes at a performance overhead when compared with using `std::unique_ptr`. TL;DR: if you are not really using this shared ownership, you should consider using `std::unique_ptr` instead

Comment: @Mike: not to argue with you, just to complement: sometimes no explicit decision about object lifetime leads to unpleasant surprises. Couple of times I had to monitor references to `shared_ptr` to find out who else keeps it alive

Comment: In both scenarios, you are returning data by value (atomic reference counter increment in #2). As the others have pointed out, both have their uses. Also, you allow the compiler to perform copy elision optimization. If the desire is to return a smart pointer, your goto should (almost) always be `std::unique_ptr` as `std::shared_ptr` can be implicitly constructed from the former.

Answer (score 3):

By default value semantic is preferred because it doesn't allocate memory => no memory leaks, no corrupted memory etc.

Each pointer type has own semantic. `shared_ptr` should be used only if the resource it controls will be *shared*, so it's important it will live until the last reference (pointer) to it. In your example `shared_ptr` is inappropriate. If its desirable to use a pointer in your example (e.g. `DBPage` is too large to store on the stack), it should be `unique_ptr`.

It's possible your example is not complete and later the result will be indeed "shared". I'd say even in this case `unique_ptr` should be used and later "converted" to `shared_ptr`, otherwise the function signature is misleading, and sometimes it's the only thing that is visible to the user. Though in this case it's arguable.

Also, `shared_ptr` is slower than `unique_ptr`, and much slower than `std::move`, because it uses atomic operations for reference counting. They are very expensive compared with simple `int.operator++`, though it's a problem only in performance critical cases.

Answer (score 2):

It depends how expensive DBPage is to copy.  If for example DBPage is a class containing some pointers to the data, it may be cheap to copy, and storing it in a `shared_ptr` might add unnecessary overhead.

On the other hand, perhaps DBPage is expensive to copy.  You mention RVO and move semantics, and those are fine when returning DBPage from a function, but if users actually want to keep two variables which refer to the same data, and they want the lifetime of the data to be the maximum of the two variables' lifetimes, then `shared_ptr` is a natural fit.

If users ultimately need `shared_ptr<DBPage>` but you give them `DBPage`, they may need to copy the data to get what they want.

In short, you need to understand your users and the actual data in play.

Answer (score 0):

You have two different situations in which you want to create an object. Your "value semantics" work well in situations where you want certain memory to be the returned object (stack memory, memory in an array, etc.). Your "reference semantics" are useful when you want your objects lifetime to exceed its scope (and live in the heap).

To specifically address your question, **choice 2 won't be readily useable when you want to store the result in a `std::vector<DBPage>`**. Even with move semantics, having the right function for the job is the better choice.

Comment: what's wrong in returning `std::vector<DBPages>` from a function? It won't be copied and it's guaranteed by the standard. Later if you need to pass ownership you can `std::move` it

Comment: @Gruffalo There's nothing wrong with returning `std::vector<DBPages>`. The issue is if you have a function returning  `std::shared_ptr<DBPage>` and want to store the result in a `std::vector<DBPage>`, you'll have to jump through hoops. I've updated my answer to make this more clear.

Comment: sorry, was confused by your last sentence